# implementar "Slug" en web apache2

Tags: webservice, apache, slug

Tengo una pequeña pagina web te testeo que tiene dos partes, el `index.html` y `contacto.html`. Tengo el servidor web montado en apache2 y tengo el `ServerName`.

Mi problema es que cuando el usuario accede a `contacto.html` su rota aparece como:

```
www.miweb.net/contacto.html
```

Pero me gustaria que quedara de esta otra forma:

```
www.miweb.net/contactemos
```

Estoy intentando buscar informacion de como se puede hacer en apache2 pero no encuentro nada, si alguien me pudriera ayudar seria de agradecer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo creo, según lo que planteas que lo que quieres es quitar la extensión de los archivos en la url. Como tu mismo lo dices, pasar de **[www.miweb.net/contacto.html](http://www.miweb.net/contacto.html)** a **[www.miweb.net/contacto](http://www.miweb.net/contacto)**

Eso lo puedes hacer con un archivo **.htaccess** que debes colocar en la raíz de tu proyecto.

```
# Quitar extensión de las URL
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# END Quitar extensión de las URL
```

Yo quito siempre las extensiones de PHP y HTML.